# How to connect to the wifi when unable to launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon in Linux mint

Tags: spring

unable to launch cinnamon session. Cinnoman.....".I tried to sudo apt-get install  --reinstall cinnamon.but it's fail to download the required file.Please help me to connect to the wifi at this situation .

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

If you find yourself on the command line in a Ubuntu based distribution of Linux, you can almost always find great guides on the internet.

[How to set up WiFi from CLI on Ubuntu Server](https://youtu.be/NCSUA7Y_QRM)